Synthesis of Gilman reagent

So I will be refering to the image attached here while explaining my query. In the synthesis of Gilman reagent, in the 3rd step, my teacher told that the (R-) from RLi will attack the partially positive Cu in R-Cu and give electrons into the vacant d orbital of copper.
The outer electronic configuration of copper is 4s1 3d10, which basically means it has no vacant d orbital. Where it can accept the electrons?
In the final structure shown towards the very end of the image, there is a negative charge on copper, which I was told is a formal charge. Can someone please explain, how the charge is formal and not an actual charge due electrons being donated to the copper by (R-) from RLi?
